# Condição no MySQL - CASE X = Y THEN Where - É possível?

Tags: mysql

Preciso buscar os produtos do meu site.

Nele, existem dois tipos: **Físicos e digitais**. Gostaria que se os produtos fossem físicos, mostrassem somente os que tivessem acima de 0 no estoque. Caso seja digital, não é necessário esse Where de estoque.

Estou fazendo desta maneira, mas está obviamente dando Syntax Error.

```
SELECT * FROM sistema_produto p 
WHERE proAtivo = 'S' 
AND proExcluido = 'N' 
AND (
    CASE `proTipo` = "F" THEN proEstoque > 0
)
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `CASE` é bem versátil, e pode ser usado em muitos contextos, mas na sua situação específica não é necessário e nem adequado.

Com o uso de `AND` e `OR` já resolve:

```
SELECT * FROM sistema_produto p 
WHERE proAtivo = 'S' 
AND proExcluido = 'N' 
AND ( `proTipo` != "F" OR proEstoque > 0 )
```

Ou seja:

- se o `proTipo` **não** for `F`, mostra sempre;
- **ou**, se for `F`, mostra só se `proEstoque` for maior que zero.

Nota: em MySQL e MariaDB, sempre que precisar, tem a função `IF( condição, valor se verdadeiro, valor se falso )` que é mais "elegante" que o `CASE` (porém, menos portátil).

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!